# Accesing variables and methods between classes using reference and singleton

Tags: c#, reference, singleton

I'm struggling with using variables and methods between classes. For example, let's focus on variable only. I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`. I have constantly changing variable in `Foo` named `number`. How do I access this variable from class `Bar`? There will be always only one instance of `Bar` class.

```
class Foo {
  private Bar bclass;
  public int number = 0;

  Foo() {
     bclass = new Bar();
  }
}

class Bar {
  Bar() {
    // code
    // Access Foo's number from here
  }
}
```

There are a few options that I can think of. First - Singleton pattern. I can make all methods and variables static, make constructor private and make only one instance. Second solution would be passing `number` as reference via constructor. But that doesn't solve my problem with accessing methods in `Foo`. Or i could pass whole instance of `Foo` to `Bar` via constructor like this:

```
 Bar(Foo firstClass) {}

 // Then in Foo
   bclass = new Bar(this);
```

My program is using 4 different classes, all of them will have always only one instance and all of them need to communicate with main class or between each other in some way (using it's variables or methods). Which approach would you recommend me? Making all 4 classes as Singletons?

Sorry if the title or text is confusing, if I missed something it something isn't clear I will gladly respond or edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to make your code unit testable, singleton is not a good option. Instantiating objects inside other as a private fields also is not a good practice because you couple your code, your better option I would say is passing the objects in a specific method (inject) in each class, better if you create interfaces:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void SetBar(IBar bar);
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    private IBar _bar;

    public void SetBar(IBar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }
}

interface IBar
{
    void SetFoo(IFoo foo);
}

class Bar : IBar
{
    private IFoo _foo;

    public void SetFoo(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    private IFoo _foo;
    private IBar _bar;

    public MainClass(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
    {
        _foo = foo;
        _bar = bar;

        _foo.SetBar(bar);
        _bar.SetFoo(foo);
    }
}

class Context // Here you build the structure you want
{
    IFoo _foo;
    IBar _bar;
    MainClass _mainClass;

    public Context()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
        _bar = new Bar();
        _mainClass = new MainClass(_foo, _bar);
    }
}
```

This way your code is loosely coupled and you can unit test it

Comment: Thank you! This is the exact answer I was looking for. Thank You and @guwere. I was looking for benefits and/or better ways how to do it and your arguments are more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could forgo singletons altogether and prefer injecting references of dependent classes in your constructor. For example if `Bar` wants information from `Foo`, you can add `Foo` as constructor parameter to `Bar`. Then in your main class you pass a new `Foo` instance to `Bar`

```
class Foo {
    //...
}

class Bar {
    private Foo _foo;
    // add Foo as a instance
    Bar(Foo foo) {
        _foo = foo;
        // access foo number here
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var bar = new Bar(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! I was thinking about this too. It will work flawlessly. But is it OK to use? Isn't there any "safer" or better way to do it?

Comment: It is my opinion that is is absolutely OK to use. As you application evolves, you may find that you need to use more than one instance of your previous single-use classes. Were you to use singleton pattern, you would later need to go back and refactor the consumer of those classes. Try to envision the scope of your application down the road and data structures it is going to use then and use right now (or shouldn't use). Unit testing, interchangeable implementations- singletons makes for harder testing. Conversely, singleton is ok for small apps for modules like file manager, config manager.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer (as well as Eddy's) helped me a lot. It's nice to read clear answer with reasons with not or why yes.

Answer (score 0):

If your class has a field or property which is declared `internal` or `public` then other classes can access that field or property. If it's `internal` then it's accessible to other classes in the same assembly (project.) If it's `public` then it's accessible to any class in that assembly or other assemblies that reference it.

```
// If the class is public then it's visible to other assemblies.
// If the class isn't public then other assemblies can't see public
// members because they can't see the class itself.
public class Foo
{
    // Accessible to classes inside the project.
    internal string SomeField; 

    // Accessible to classes outside the project.
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

That's the direct answer to your question. In practice we almost never expose fields (variables) outside of a class. Think of those fields as the internal state of the class. In order to make it work predictably and prevent bugs we don't want other classes changing the state of this class.

Here's an example. (I'm not crazy about car examples, but whatever.)

```
public class Car
{
    public int SpeedMilesPerHour;
}
```

The problem is that any other class can set `SpeedMilesPerHour` to anything. It can go from zero to 8,000 to -10,000,000. That's probably not the intent for the `Car`, and if your car is driving 3,000mph or -20mph then you likely have a bug.

You can't really expect every other class to know how fast the `Car` should be able to go and when. You would have duplicate code all over the place to make sure the speed is set correctly.

You solve this problem by having the `Car` "hide" its speed variable and control how it changes. For example, it might look like this:

```
public class Car
{
    private int _speed;

    public int Speed { get { return _speed; } }

    public void GoFaster()
    {
        if (_speed < 200) _speed++;
    }

    public void SlowDown()
    {
        if (_speed > 0) _speed--;
    }
}
```

Now `_speed` is internal. We've added a property so that other classes can *see* the speed. But the only way to change it is by calling `SpeedUp()` or `SlowDown()`. The class won't allow other classes to mess up its internal state by changing the speed unexpectedly or setting it to invalid number.

One of the best ways to learn is just to experiment.

- Create a console app
- Even easier, create a unit test project. Same thing, but you can have a bunch of tests you can run instead of one console app that you edit.
- Use [https://dotnetfiddle.net/](.NET Fiddle). This is convenient when you want to provide an easy way for someone else to run your code.

Comment: I'm aware of exposing variables and that they should be wrapped with properties. But that doesn't solve my problem. To access internal property of class A from class B, I still need at least instance of class A or make the property static.

Comment: I had a hunch that I wasn't exactly hitting the nail on the head. But it's a little unclear from the question. The title looks like it's about how to access the values. Can you just create an instance of the class and maintain a single static instance of it? You can use a class as a singleton (sort of) by only creating one instance and re-using it without actually having the make the class a singleton or give it static properties.

Comment: Or, even better than a static instance is having one class that orchestrates the behavior of the other classes. That class passes a single instance of a class to other classes so they can interact with it. The trouble with having singletons or having one class point to a static instance of another class is that it creates a global state. Generally speaking that can lead to maintenance difficult and bugs. The global state becomes wrong or unexpected and it's hard to track it down because multiple classes are accessing it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I couldn't express myself probably. I need to access properties and methods of class B in class A (A->B)and vice-versa from B call methods of class A (B->A). I think that the easiest way is to make all methods static in all classes. And then call just A.Method(). But I feel it's terrible wrong and there is another way. I have 4 classes and they all need to access methods of other classes.There should be only once instance of each class so I was thinking about singletons.Then I would have program only made of singletons. Isn't there any other way? Or this is absolutely normal?

Comment: Reacting to your last message - I was thinking the same. Static methods and variables could cause me a lot of troubles. So do you think it's safe and good to send instances via constructor like `Bar(Foo instanceOfFoo)` ?

Comment: Yes, that was described in the other answer. That's a great way to have classes interact with each other. That answer contains the word "inject," a reference to dependency injection. Unfortunately I wrote code for years without ever learning that concept, but when I did it made a great difference.